# Scaling Puppet 7.x

Tags: puppet

I have been referring to https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7.1/server/scaling_puppet_server.html when looking at building a scaled Puppet environment.

I have the Puppet CA functioning, the problem I get to is step 2 with the Puppet compile section which is lacking a decent example or details.

> In the compiler's webserver.conf file, add and set the following SSL settings:
>
> - ssl-cert
> - ssl-key
> - ssl-ca-cert
> - ssl-crl-path

The compile host is able to send a request to the CA and once the cert is signed on the CA, gets it back fine. I am not sure what to put for the above settings. CA services have been disabled on the compile host as directed but when attempting to start pupperserver, it fails to load due to CaService not found so at the moment I am assuming it is due to the above.

> 2021-01-12T13:12:34.276+11:00 ERROR [main] [p.t.internal] Error during
> app buildup! java.lang.RuntimeException: Service ':CaService' not
> found

A google search doesn't return much in regards to this topic so any useful pointers about setting up this type of environment would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working. In regards to the webserver.conf settings, I used the following:

> ```
> ssl-cert: "/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/<server FQDN>.pem"
> ssl-key: "/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/<server FQDN>.pem"
> ssl-ca-cert: "/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem"
> ssl-crl-path: "/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/crl.pem"
> ```

Unfortunately, I still received the CAService error when attempting to start puppetserver. This turned out to be a simple mistake. Within the /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/services.d/ca.cfg I had correctly commented out the following line:

> #puppetlabs.services.ca.certificate-authority-service/certificate-authority-service

but I missed uncommenting the following line:

> puppetlabs.services.ca.certificate-authority-disabled-service/certificate-authority-disabled-service

Once the line was uncommented, the puppetserver started and my test agent was able to get a signed certificate from the centralised CA and the config from the compile master successfully.

Answer (score 1):

An overview of the `webserver.conf` config file is presented [in the Puppet docs](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7.1/server/config_file_webserver.html).  It happens to provide an example that covers all of those particular items, and it links to [detailed documentation](https://github.com/puppetlabs/trapperkeeper-webserver-jetty9/blob/master/doc/jetty-config.md).

One of the main ideas around Puppet scalability is that you can add compile servers to your pool, behind a load balancer or DNS round-robin service for a common hostname.  But one of the main issues there is that agents expect to establish SSL connections with the compile server identified by a specific certname, so you must ensure that each compile server has a cert bearing that name.  Rather than sharing one cert among multiple servers,  this is normally done by generating separate certificates for the compile servers that all bear the expected name as a *DNS Subject Alternative Name*.  The `ssl-cert` and `ssl-key` properties identify the appropriate cert.

For their part, the compile servers need to validate that client certificates have been signed by the expected CA, and for that they need the CA's certificate.  This is what the `ssl-ca-cert` setting is about.

Also, from time to time you may need to revoke certificates -- typically, when an agent node is taken out of service or its cert is somehow lost.  The CA will maintain a certificate revocation list, but for the compile servers to take it into account, the CRL must be published to them.  The `ssl-crl-path` setting tells each compile master where to find that.

---

I am inclined to think that the scaling docs are a bit out of order, however.  With the possible exception of `ssl-crl-path`, I would expect the default values of the parameters described in step #2 to be appropriate, provided that you follow all *other* steps prior to trying to start the puppetserver service on the compile server(s) you are trying to configure.  The last two steps will require `puppetserver` to be running already on the CA machine, and to be accessible through all relevant firewalls; if that is not the case then it might explain the error you report.  Note also the comments at the end of step 4 if you have previously started components out of order.

If puppetserver still does not start after you have obtained the needed host certificate via steps 4-6, then you may need to manually copy the CA server's certificate to the compile server, and set the `ssl-ca-cert` property to its location.  I remain doubtful that you will need to explicitly set `ssl-cert` or `ssl-key` if you have obtained a host cert according to the specified procedure.